# Filter Post Title without affecting screen-reader-text

Tags: filters, title, excerpt, read-more

Let's consider this code:

```
add_filter('the_title', static function ($title) {
    return $title. '-boom';
});
```

Works fine, and adds '-boom' near all the titles.

But, I also noticed that in some themes (Twenty Twenty, Twenty One and most likely many others) if a post contains the `<!--more-->` tag, this also affect the "continue reading" button, see image attached

[image]

As you can see the span class "screen reader text" is also affected.
Since I want to add some html close to the_title, this breaks the layout.

How to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution.

I've found the filter `excerpt_more` that is used to show the string shown within the more link (if theme use standard WP functions).

So, to achieve this, we need to hook the `excerpt_more` and use a lower priority of the one used by the theme.

In my example, this

```
add_filter('the_title', static function ($title) {
    return $title. '-boom';
});
```

adds `-boom` string in both text and excpert, and this

```
add_filter('excerpt_more', function ($more_link_element) {
    $more_link_element = str_replace('-boom', '', $more_link_element);
    return $more_link_element;
},9999,1);
```

removes it from the excpert